# Why are my external resources not being loaded (in many cases) via URL/Loaders in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing a Flash game, which loads resources from a local url. This url is resolved locally and is something like http://example.dev. This only holds static resources, so something like http://example.dev/images/randomtiles/grass.png is, actually, a valid image if I hit the resource via `curl`.

However, I'm using two browsers to test. One is Google Chrome with Adobe Flash Player 15.0.0.189, and another one is Firefox with Adobe Flash Player 11.2.202.457. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (perhaps this is a bug and not an 8-layer issue).

In AFP 15, hitting the url http://example.dev/images/randomtiles/grass.png does not work at all. In AFP 11, hitting the url http://example.dev/images/randomtiles/grass.png works only if I am connected to Internet. Hitting the url with `curl` works always. Hitting the url with Chrome or Firefox directly, works always.

The mechanism used to hit the images via flash is a bit long to explain, but it is basically based in Loaders:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
    try {
        addCacheCallback(entry, Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content));
    } catch(e:Error) {
        errorCallback(e);
    }
});
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorCallback);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://example.dev/images/randomtiles/grass.png"));
```

**What do I expect**: Since the resources server is maintained locally (in this machine), I expect the resources are **always** served in my game, regardless the flash version.

What's going on with Flash Player? Or... what did I miss there? (Cannot debug due to problems with the environment I'm still struggling with).

Comment: you never say what error are showing up when loading fails.

Comment: Cannot see any error in browser (still struggling with debug).

Comment: Add listeners for errors - `IOError`, `SecurityError`, and maybe even `Error` just to be sure.. Then you can log them somehow (or even put the text inside `TextField` on stage)

Comment: Sounds like a security sandboxing issue.  As Andrey suggested, reporting your errors may highlight where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `.swf` file served from the same domain?

If not you have to add a `crossdomain.xml` file to your site. [This documentation](//help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html) may help.

The easiest way to test whether this is the problem you're experiencing is to add a file named `crossdomain.xml` to your site root:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml --> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
  <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Note that in practice, you would want to specifically whitelist the domains that should be permitted access.